# How to achieve brighter shininess using GL_LIGHT1?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have this image

[image]

Is there a way to achieve brighter look of the light without editing specular material part of the code?
This is my current code:

```
void drawTeapot() {
    GLfloat mat_diffuse[] = {0.2, 1.0, 0.8, 1.0};
    GLfloat mat_specular[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    GLfloat mat_shininess[] = {128.0};

    GLfloat lmodel_ambient[] = {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0};
    GLfloat light_position[] = {1.1, 1.1, 1.0, 1.0};
    GLfloat light_specular[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, light_position);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);
    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, lmodel_ambient);

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);

    glutSolidTeapot(0.5);
    }
```

I have to use `GL_LIGHT1` because there is another function that reacts to mouse clicks and turns that light on and off. Therefore, I can't have the specular on the object before the light turns on. It has to remain matte, sort of. As you can see, shininess is on max, specular also, but it's not really what I'm going for. I basically want it to be tiny bit bigger that it is now, more dispersed.

Comment: I suggest using a modern pipeline with a shader to be able to model your lightning exactly as you need.

Comment: @Acorn unfortunately, I have to use this older approach.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Out of curiosity, for what kind of system/field is this for?

Comment: @me995 If you want to get a more _dispersed_ effect, then you have to reduce the shininess. Further note, the value for `glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPECULAR, ...)` and  `glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, ...)` can be different. It is even possible to use values greater than 1.0

Comment: I didn't know that I could use values greater than 1.0! Again, you solved everything. Thank you @Rabbid76.

Comment: @Acorn I don't really follow, what do you mean?

Comment: @me995 I mean: in which topic/sub-field of computer science or engineering is being used? (for example: a game, a physics simulation visualization, an engineering CAD program, a medical device...). It is always interesting to learn where fixed-pipeline is still being used, because it is very rare nowadays.

Comment: @Acorn it's just introduction to computer graphics course. Nothing special, just some basics we need to learn.

Comment: @me995 Ah, alright, thanks!